# Centroid algorithm for text classification, tools?

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, document-classification, centroid

As discussed [here](http://classes.seattleu.edu/computer_science/csse470/Madani/ABCs.html#centroid), Do you know of any tools which provides a centroid algorithm for text classification in java?

Answer (score 3):

[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) includes this as the class [`NearestCentroid`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-centroid-classifier). It also includes an implementation of L2-normalized tf-idf.

[Disclaimer: I'm a scikit-learn developer.]

Comment: Thanks but do you know anything in Java?

Comment: @user601: nope, sorry. It's not very hard to implement, though.

Comment: Hi, so assuming my training instances are [1,5,1,0],[0,1,3,2]; then the centroid will be [1,6,4,2]/2 = [0.5,3,2,1] right?

Comment: If those are the only two samples of a particular class and you're using Euclidean distance, then yes.

Comment: Isn't it just the average? How does the Euclidean distance involves here when building the centroid?

Comment: Yes, it's the average. You need a distance metric when you want to predict (classify unseen instances) using the resulting model. Then, average corresponds to Euclidean distance, while the median corresponds to Manhattan (L1) distance.

Comment: ok Thanks! I was just wondering what if I use K-means and let number of centroids built to 1 (i.e., k=1) to build a centroid and when unseen instances comes I use that centroid to calculate the distances with the unseen instance? Is this way wrong?

Comment: @user601: k-means with k=1 makes no sense; it puts the entire training set in a single class. Classifying with a k-means clustering where k>2 makes sense, but ignores the labeling of your dataset.

Comment: yes with k=1, I build a single centroid of all the training instances, which is used to to calculate the distance with test instances. Should work as the centroid algorithm in that link right?

Comment: @user601: with k=1, there is only one class/cluster. There is no decision to be made. Besides, you certainly don't need k-means to find the single centroid of a bunch of data points. Just average them.

Comment: I really appreciate you being helpful. Thank you.